# Moving a pictures to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need help making a Macro move a picture to cell in excel. I can move a picture up, down, left and right. But I want the macro to move a picture to a cell (for example to cell B7) no matter where it is in the excel sheet.

I have tried using

```
 Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -474.7059055118
 Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -303.5293700787
End Sub
```

this moves the picture, just not to the right spot

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Left` and `Top` properties of the shape and the cell.

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Left = [B7].Left
Selection.ShapeRange.Top = [B7].Top
```